# Json jcarousel not reading li tags

Tags: json, jcarousel

I posted before but now I know the cause of the problem - I'm using json and jcarousel.  I am having an issue with jcarousel reading the number of li tags.  I think it is becuase they are being generated by the json and in a div.

```
$.getJSON("myurl.com", function(data){        
  $.each(data.myproducts, function(i,item){          
    $("#myproducts").append("<li>"+item.name+"</li>");         
  });      
});
```

If I hard code the li tags after the div that contains the carousel, it works but that is not practical.  Any suggestions on how to display the json li tags so that the carousel can read them?

Comment: are you declaring the carousel BEFORE or AFTER you add the tags? Usually you have to declare (or inform the plugin afterwards) plugins after you have your elements on the page. Check and see how carousel lets you add stuff after.